# Jquery finding set of element by attribute and wrapping them in a new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapall

I have a bunch of `<ul>`s that have the attribute data-year.  I want to wrap the data-year attributes with the same value in a div like so: `<div class="year"><div>`

before:

```
<div class="projectLists">
    <ul data-year="2013">
        <li>items ...   
    </ul>
    <ul data-year="2013">
        <li>items...
    </ul>
    <ul data-year="2012">
        <li>items ...
    </ul>
    <ul data-year="2012">
        <li>items ...
    </ul>
    <ul data-year="2011">
        <li>items...
    </ul>
    <ul data-year="2011">
        <li>items...
    </ul>
</div>
```

after should look like this:

```
<div class="projectLists">
<div class="year">
    <ul data-year="2013">
        <li>items ...
    </ul>
    <ul data-year="2013">
        <li>items...
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="year">
    <ul data-year="2012">
        <li>items ...
    </ul>
    <ul data-year="2012">
        <li>items...
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="year">
    <ul data-year="2011">
        <li>items ...
    </ul>
    <ul data-year="2011">
        <li>items...
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I've tried this which wraps every ul multiple times and does not have the intended results:

```
$('.projectList ul').each(function(){
        var year = $(this).attr('data-year');
        //alert(year)
        console.log(year);

        $('.projectList ul[data-year=' + year + ']').wrapAll('<div class="year">');
        $('.projectList ul[data-year=' + year + ']').eq(0).before('<h2>'+ year +'</h2>');

});
```

any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var $ul = $('.projectLists > ul'),
    years = {};

$ul.each(function(){
   years[$(this).data('year')] = '';
});

for (year in years) {
  $ul.filter('[data-year='+ year +']').wrapAll('<div class="year"></div');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ghvUV/

Comment: Using object keys as a unique array.... Nice. Never saw that before. Just don't forget to check `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: This is a good solution for finding the unique years since object keys must be unique.

Comment: @JosephSilber Actually this is the first time that I have used object's keys as unique identifiers. Using `hasOwnProperty` is a good suggestion and a good practice, but I think it's not necessary in this case. thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $lists = $('.projectLists > ul'),
    years = [];

$lists.each(function() {
    var year = this.getAttribute('data-year');
    if ( ! ~$.inArray(year, years) ) {
        years.push(year);
    }
});

$.each(years, function (i, year) {
    $lists.filter('[data-year=' + year + ']').wrapAll('<div class="year">');
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CKxy8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Get an array containing the unique set of years, iterate over that array, for each year select all the ul elements with that year and wrap them in a new div.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the parent when iterating through to see if you've already added a class of "year". The code below works as you expect. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMaGS/)

```
$('.projectLists ul').each(function(){
    var year = $(this).attr('data-year');

    if(!$(this).parent().hasClass("year")) {
        $(".projectLists ul[data-year='"+year+"']").wrapAll('<div class="year">');
        $(".projectLists ul[data-year='"+year+"']").eq(0).before('<h2>'+ year +'</h2>');
    }

});
```

Comment: this wraps each year separately, however i can already see this solution coming in handy in another context.  very cool. thanks.

Comment: @mwu56 I linked to the wrong jsFiddle. My code, however, does what you intend. I've updated my jsFiddle so you can take a look.